# Help to solve Simultaneous Equations

Tags: equation-solving

I think this should be easy to numerically solve in Mathematica, but for some reason I'm not finding the correct way to do it.

I basically want to solve these simyltaneous equiations:

```
NSolve[
{
-(0.7)*w + (0.3)*y + (0.4)*z == 0,
-(0.6)*x + (0.2)*y + (0.1)*z == 0,
(0.5)*w + (0.3)*x - y == 0,
(0.2)*w + (0.3)*x + (0.5)*y - (0.5)*z == 0,                                \
w + x + y + z == 1
}, 
{z , w , x , y}]
```

This is what i see:

[image]

Comment: `NSolve` instead of nslove - capitalization matters.

Comment: no difference. I think Mathematica corrects the input even if it's in plain english

Comment: don't get why the -1.

Comment: …No difference? Don't tell me that you always press "Ctrl+=" before you write the code.

Comment: Oh, you corrected it: then the code can be run with no problem.

Comment: I should be missing something, because it runs but doesn't solve the equations as shown in the screenshot that I just added.

Comment: 囧, you don't press "Ctrl+=" but "="……then you're not calculate with mma, you're calculate with Wolfram|Alpha, a site like google… in fact even with "=" we can get the answer, but, you write a "\" after the 4th equation, see?

Comment: you are right. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @whynot The problem was that you evaluated your command as free form input (shortcut `=`). If you evaluated it with `shift + enter` you would get a correct result.

Comment: @Artes I think "=" means Wolfram|Alpha and "Ctrl+=" means free form input…

Comment: @xzczd  Clicking plus in a notebook opens a window which says : `==` - `Wolfram|Alpha` query, `=` - `Free-form` input, etc.

Comment: @Artes ……Why??? The document `guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn80` don't say like this!

Comment: @xzczd `Ctrl+=` + `some text` tries to convert `some text`  to inline Mathematica input, while `=` at beginning of input tries to  generate Mathematica output from free-form input. E.g look at `guide/WolframAlphaIntegration`.

Comment: @Artes Ah… I don't expect that the document contains this kind of mistake…whatever, I never use this, I always think it's an embarrassing function in Mma 8.

Comment: @Artes I cut the Internet and found "=" won't work, so `guide/WolframAlphaIntegration` and `guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn80` are both correct…: `=` at beginning of input tries to generate Mathematica output from free-form input with Wolfram|Alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Clear[x, y, z, w];
eq1 = -0.7*w + 0.3*y + 0.4*z == 0;
eq2 = -0.6*x + 0.2*y + 0.1*z == 0;
eq3 = 0.5*w + 0.3*x - y == 0;
eq4 = 0.2*w + 0.3*x + 0.5*y - 0.5*z == 0;
eq5 = w + x + y + z == 1;
Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, {z, w, x, y}]
```

The result is

```
{{z -> 0.384513, w -> 0.300401, x -> 0.126836, y -> 0.188251}}
```

I removed unnecessary parentheses. It seems that they were misleading for Mathematica.

The solution of 5 equation with 4 variables is possible, since the determinant of first 4 equations is zero:

```
  m = {{-0.7, 0, 0.3, 0.4}, {0, -0.6, 0.2, 0.1}, {0.5, 0.3, -1, 
    0}, {0.2, 0.3, 0.5, -0.5}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
m[[1 ;; 4]] // Det // Chop

0
```

You could have skip one of them.